# How can I visualize Spark Streaming data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote a PySpark script that processes websocket data near real time and I would like to visualize the data using graphs and tables that changes periodically. 
The only way I can think of doing this is creating a REST API interface and using JavaScript libraries to create graphs that refresh at certain time intervals. 
Is there a framework for Spark Streaming that makes data visualization easier?

Also, is it possible to connect Spark Stream to Spark SQL? If so I can use BI tools such as tableau for visualization.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Zeppelin, Databrics for example. Notebooks have some visualizations

Comment: Btw Look at Structured Streaming

Comment: look into this github repo [spark-streaming-visualize](https://github.com/Ranlot/spark-streaming-visualize)